# Excessive Number of Thread Pools in Java when looping with TimeLimitedCodeBlock

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I wrote a Java program that seems to work fine, but when I check the memory tab of the Activity Monitor on my Mac I see that the number of "Ports" associated with the Java VM is a huge number, currently about 49,000 and rising steadily as I use the program.  I'm not sure if this is a problem or not, but given that the other programs listed in Activity Monitor tend to have far fewer ports (less than 1000) and those numbers don't seem to be rising continuously, I'm concerned that my program is leaving some garbage in its wake that eventually is going to cause a problem.

Troubleshooting so far has isolated the source of the increasing port count to code that executes inside a TimeLimitedCode block that follows the example here:
[Java: set timeout on a certain block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715235/java-set-timeout-on-a-certain-block-of-code) .

Every time the code loops through the TimeLimited block, it creates a new thread pool, as shown in the output pasted below from a  sample program almost identical to the one in the link.  You can see each time through the loop the pool number is incremented by 1 from pool-1 to pool-2, etc.

On my actual program the thread pool count quickly gets into the tens of thousands and this shows up in my Mac's activity monitor as a huge number of ports associated with the Java VM... currently at about 49,000. A guide to the Mac Activity Monitor describe those "ports" this way:

*The "ports" column shows how many "Mach ports", or "kernel queues" the process has open, which basically describes how communicative the process can be with others (ie: reserving memory usage from the system).*

That suggests to me that all those ports are eating up some system resources that need to be released somehow.  But I don't really know where to start -- would appreciate comments about 1) whether my "problem" really is one, and 2) what kind of troubleshooting I should do to track down the root cause.

Thanks.

```
    0ms [            main] calling runWithTimeout!
   53ms [ pool-1-thread-1] starting sleep!
 1055ms [            main] got timeout!
 1055ms [ pool-1-thread-1] was interrupted!
 1055ms [            main] end of main method!
 1055ms [            main] calling runWithTimeout!
 1056ms [ pool-2-thread-1] starting sleep!
 2061ms [            main] got timeout!
 2061ms [            main] end of main method!
 2061ms [            main] calling runWithTimeout!
 2061ms [ pool-2-thread-1] was interrupted!
 2061ms [ pool-3-thread-1] starting sleep!
 3063ms [            main] got timeout!
 3063ms [            main] end of main method!
 3064ms [            main] calling runWithTimeout!
 3063ms [ pool-3-thread-1] was interrupted!
 3064ms [ pool-4-thread-1] starting sleep!
 4068ms [            main] got timeout!
 4068ms [ pool-4-thread-1] was interrupted!
```

Comment: Do you do the executor.shutDown() part of that code?  We might need to see your actual code.

Comment: Yes, I used the entire "public class TimeLimitedCodeBlock" posted by Neeme Praks on that page, and used his sample program below as my starting point, just replacing his try {
            log(startTime, "starting sleep!");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            log(startTime, "woke up!");
          }  with a call to my other code.

Comment: It could be that there is a problem in the other code that I called... it is a large package written by someone else, but I do have all the source code so can work through it... just not sure what to be on the lookout for  exactly...