# Creating a new thread in a Spring webservice

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am currently maintaining a large Spring MVC application which sits on top of a large enterprise Java application. The purpose of the Spring MVC in my area is to display to support the current status of the application - it does this by firing off health checks to various different modules of the application.

I currently want to install a timeout for this, by launching the health test in a seperate thread and using `ExecutorService` to do the timing and killing if the thread takes longer than x amount of seconds. I followed [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715235/java-set-timeout-on-a-certain-block-of-code/19183452) and encapsulated my `HealthCheckRunner` (which takes in a `HealthCheck`) into a `Runnable` class which I called `HealthCheckWorker`. The current implementation looks like this:

```
                        HealthCheckWorker hcw = new HealthCheckWorker(healthCheck,runner);
                        Thread thread = new Thread(hcw);

                        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                        final Future future = executor.submit(thread);
                        executor.shutdown(); 
                        future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

However, I am getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.` error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: are you using tomcat or an application srver as jboss/wildfly and so on?

Comment: @ValerioVaudi yes, it is tomcat

Comment: ok it migth seem stiupid the  my question but for instance thd more recent application server dont oermit instance manualy thread

Comment: @ValerioVaudi let's assume you're correct. How would I get tomcat to make a new thread? I'm quite new, as you can tell :)

Comment: You're most probably trying to access a request-scoped bean from your background thread, which is not associated to the request. Just... don't. Pass the state needed by the background thread to the runnable constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use [@Async](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async). You get a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) having a `cancel` method.

Comment: That won't fix the problem, though.

Comment: @ JB Nizet - That's right. The @Async-annotated method would needed to be supplied with all needed information up-front (as method parameters), similar to what your the comment under the question suggests. I missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question here is how you can achieve this

```
@Configuration
public class ListenerConfig {

    @Bean
    public RequestContextFilter requestContextFilter() {
        RequestContextFilter requestContextFilter = new RequestContextFilter();
        requestContextFilter.setThreadContextInheritable(true);
        return requestContextFilter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very complex answer correctly at this question. The my first advice was, if you want use some data that are related to the web thread is more correct take this data and built the healt service as loose copled service respect to the web context in order to scale as you want. If you be able to design the your HealthChecker in a way you have many option for scale you may use a Spring Integration pipeline with a timeout on the gateway, use a messaging system as ActiveMq, Rabit and so on or use the multi thead approch as in your question, but the keypoint hear is that if the process of heatlchaking is complex becouse I don't know yon must aggregate some data from more data source or somting like that, but if the your service is decopled to data that you had only in the thrad local of your web request yon should not have problem like your and you can benefit of many option for scale the your service

I hope that this reflection can help you to find a solution