# How to get mp4 video duration faster in Android java

Tags: android, performance, video, video-streaming, metadata

This is performance question. Application start media scanning and store duration in database, this process takes time for large number of videos. Please any one help me to faster this process by getting duration faster from url or inputStream. I need piece of code to get only duration (can be low level code like from internal class of exo-player etc)
Currently I used

```
mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoUrl, new HashMap<>());
            String durationString = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(durationString)){
                duration = Long.parseLong(durationString);
            }else {
                App.toast("got null duration for "+videoUrl);
            }
```

But this takes longer. I am considering to raise timeout exception for above code bock using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19183452/5710872) but it not the solution.
Other I try this too using `mp4parser`

```
duration = new IsoFile(Channels.newChannel(getInputStream(file.getPath()))).getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().getDuration();
```

but this also has a lot of things inside solution.

Thanks pros!

Comment: If the videos are already indexed by the `MediaStore`, [get the `DURATION` from there](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.html#DURATION).

Comment: No Sir, We support file system that OS doesn't. So we index them-self. Yes, I am doing this during indexing

Comment: @CommonsWare What could be the reasons of blockage or latency? and Is there any other better solution that works with steams. Otherwise this question may not pointing to actual problem and not be useful

Comment: "What could be the reasons of blockage or latency?" -- I have no idea, sorry.