# Fallback to methodB if methodA execution takes more than X seconds in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hystrix

I have a Spring Boot application and I have one `@Service` that is quite heavy and can execute from 0.5 to 5 seconds. I would like it to stop execution if execution time exceeds 1 second and fallback to a fallback method.

```
/// entry point
public String longLatingMethod(Payload payload) {
    /// long lasting operation that can take up to 5 seconds
    return value; 
}

// I want this method to be executed if `longLatingMethod` takes more than 1 second to execute.
public String fallbackMethod(Payload payload) {
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Right now I have implemented it with `Hystrix` framework, but since `Hystrix` is being discontinued, I would like to know what are other libraries for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Future in particular the method [`V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)):

> Waits if necessary for at most the given time for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result, if available.

And use it as follow:

```
  Callable<String> task = () -> {
    ...
  };

   public Future<String> myMethod() {
     return Executors.submit(task);
   }

   public String fallBackMethod() {
      ...
   }

   String value = null;
   try {
      Future<String> result = myMethod.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      value = result.get();
   } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      value = fallBackMethod();
   }
```

Note that you can't stop the execution of a method once it started if you don't modify that method checking periodically if it has finished or not, but often you can't, for example if you are asking for a query on a database and the query takes 5 seconds you can't check before 5 seconds.

Comment: Sounds like a solution. I do not need to stop original method, so all good. Why is this answer downvoted?

Comment: @SergeiLedvanov no idea :-D But if it works please flag it as the right solution and upvote. Thanks

Comment: it feels like it should work, haven't tested though.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to run your task in some sort of thread so that you can continue execution and wait (for a certain number of milliseconds) for that process to finish. If it doesn't finish in the allotted time then interrupt the primary task and run the backup task. Note that your primary task will have to check if it is interrupted, blocking operations often check for this already and will stop blocking when interrupted.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        // your long running task here...
        System.out.println("running primary task");

        // simulate it taking too long...
        // will need to check if it is interrupted if you want to terminate it sooner
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("primary task interrupted");
        }
    });
    t.start();

    // one second threshold
    try { t.join(1000); } catch (Exception e) {}

    if (t.isAlive()) {
        // if the primary task is still running interrupt it
        t.interrupt();

        // run your backup task
        System.out.println("running backup task");
        // ...
        System.out.println("backup task completed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("primary task completed");
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
running primary task
running backup task
primary task interrupted
backup task completed
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it is the best solution, but check this question: [Java: set timeout on a certain block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715235/java-set-timeout-on-a-certain-block-of-code)

And in the timeout catch block add the fallback

```
final Runnable stuffToDo = new Thread() {
  @Override 
  public void run() { 
    /* Do stuff here. */ 
  }
};

final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
final Future future = executor.submit(stuffToDo);
executor.shutdown(); // This does not cancel the already-scheduled task.

try { 
  future.get(1, TimeUnit.Seconds); 
}
catch (InterruptedException ie) { 
  /* Handle the interruption. Or ignore it. */ 
}
catch (ExecutionException ee) { 
  /* Handle the error. Or ignore it. */ 
}
catch (TimeoutException te) { 
    return fallbackMethod(payload);
}
```

Comment: Haven't downvoted your answer myself, but you'd better include some of the  referenced code in your answer. That way if that answer gets removed/updated yours keeps being self-explanatory.